# How do I work out if a modal view is still visible or has finally closed after an indeterminant time using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I have a modal view which asks the user for certain details such as title, description etc for a list creation task on a website. Once you have entered all the details you can click save and the modal view takes a few seconds to save (shows a spinner) then closes.

My issue is that I can't find any way other than manually specifying time.sleep(5) (which is crazy inefficient) to work out when its safe to click the next button after the save action.

The save action can sometimes take longer than 4 or 5 seconds depending on network conditions and volume of data being saved. I've tried using the .is_displayed(), isEnabled(), referencing the element but nothing seems to work. If an element like the save button on the modal is present I can find it but as soon as the modal is closed the code disappears from the DOM and the found element is out of scope and causes the try, except to trigger.

Is it really this hard or am I making a silly mistake that I'm just not seeing?

For reference, the webpage loads the modal in a div, before and after the modal is not displayed:

`<div id="modal-outlet"></div>`

and during the modal display (just the start of the block as its quite a large amount of code):

```
<div id="modal-outlet"><div aria-hidden="false" id="ember1234" class="modal-overlay modal-overlay--layer-default modal-overlay--is-top-layer  ember-view">      <div data-test-modal="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal modal--layer-default edit-content-modal" size="x-large" aria-labelledby="-edit-content-modal">
        <span class="a11y-text">Dialog content start.</span>
        <button data-test-modal-close-btn=""
```

if any of that HTML backstory helps. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method, `wait_for_element_not_visible()`, which uses `EC.invisibility_of_element()` to wait for an element to no longer be visible:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def wait_for_element_not_visible(
    driver, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
):
    try:
        return WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element((by, selector))
        )
    except Exception:
        raise Exception(
            "Element {%s} was still visible after %s seconds!"
            % (selector, timeout)
        )
```

From your code, you would then be able to call:

```py
wait_for_element_not_visible(driver, "#modal-outlet")
```

And the wait will continue until the element is no longer visible, or the wait lasts longer than the timeout, in which case an exception is raised.